# Migrate from German TFS to VSO

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We're running a German TFS 2013.4 on premise and want to move to Visual Studio Online. The OpsHub migration tool stops with a template mismatch.

I ran the TeamProjectManager tool (https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/) and compared our template to the VSO template. The fields are there, but their names are different, one is German and one is English ("Fehler" vs "bug").

Would it be possible to convert our local TFS to English? It's a single-machine installation running in a VM, so we can take a snapshot and just try it. We don't have any customizations, but TFS was upgraded several times, all the way back from TFS 2008. I read somewhere that might leave behind some obsolete fields, which can also cause problems.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Currently such feature is not supported in OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility.  The question for language conversion can be best answered by Microsoft Support. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I believe you would still have to rename your Work Item types even if you changed your server to English.

Do you need the history in VSO?  Would it suffice to export TFS Work Items to Excel, map the fields and import to VSO?  Obviously version control history would not be carried over either but you would still have the on-premise archive.

The TFS Integration Tools would likely do the job but they are NOT fun to use.
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe

*Sorry, this would have been a comment rather than an answer but SO wouldn't let me add one.

Comment: I changed the settings in the migration tool to only copy the source code, which worked without any problems (took about 11 hours to migrate 7000 changesets). We then manually added the open work items to VSO, which is good enough to continue working.